# How can metadata.json properties be changed after a token is minted?

Tags: transaction, cardano-cli, mint, metadata.json

I've minted a token but some of the metadata.jsosn properties don't look so great. Is there a way to update them?

The general form I've tried is:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
        --fee $fee \
        --tx-in $txhash#$txix \
        --tx-out $address+$output \
        --metadata-json-file metadata.json  \
        --out-file matx.raw
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you cannot change the metadata for a token once its minted. Thats the whole point of putting something on the blockchain-its immutable. On Cardano, token metadata is just metadata in the minting transaction. What you are doing is just adding new metadata to a new transaction with the token. This is not changing the minting metadata. You should just burn the token and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
export address="address the token was created on"
export txhash="transaction hash the token was create don"
export txix="index of txhash above"
export funds="funds at the txhash"
export policyid="the token policy id"
export fee="0"
export output="0"
export tokenamount="the countof the token at the txhash"

cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
        --fee $fee \
        --tx-in $txhash#$txix \
        --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $tokenpolicy.$tokenname" \
        --metadata-json-file metadata.json  \
        --out-file matx.raw

fee=`cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee --tx-body-file matx.raw --tx-in-count 1 --tx-out-count 1 --witness-count 1 --mainnet --protocol-params-file=protocol.json | cut -d " " -f1`
echo "Funds? $funds"
echo "Fee? $fee"
output=$(expr $funds - $fee)
echo "Output? $output"
echo "Addr? $address"
echo "txhash: $txhash#$txix"

# redo the transaction aboev w/correct fee
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
        --fee $fee  \
        --tx-in $txhash#$txix \
        --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $tokenpolicy.$tokenname" \
        --metadata-json-file metadata.json  \
        --out-file matx.raw \

# sign the transaction
cardano-cli transaction sign \
            --signing-key-file test.skey \
            --signing-key-file policy/policy.skey \
            --tx-body-file matx.raw \
             --mainnet \
            --out-file matx.signed

# submit the transaction
cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file  matx.signed --mainnet
```